# ggplot Colour-labelling

Tags: r, ggplot2

Simple question: I have the dataframe, `df`, below, I can scatter-plot and colour-label based on the `label` column of `df`:

```
if(!require("ggplot2")) { install.packages("ggplot2");  require("ggplot2") }
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(a= rnorm(30, mean=1, sd=1),
                b= rnorm(30, mean=5, sd =2),
                labels= sample(c(1,2,3), 30, replace=TRUE ))
ggplot(data= df, aes(x=a, y=b)) +  
geom_point(data= df, colour=df$labels, shape=1)
```

However, I do not know how I can specify the actual colours (e.g. pink, magenta, cyan) for labelling.

I tried adding the code below to the ggplot but it does not work:

```
scale_colour_manual( name = "Name", values = c(1 = "pink", 
                                               2 = "magenta",
                                               3 = "cyan"))
```

How can I specify the colour in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `aes` if you want to specify colors in the data. In addition, you need to use `factor`, if you want to use a discrete scale. And you should quote the numbers in `values`.

```
ggplot(data= df, aes(x=a, y=b)) +  
  geom_point(aes(colour=factor(labels)), shape=1) +
  scale_colour_manual( name = "Name", values = c("1" = "pink", 
                                                 "2" = "magenta",
                                                 "3" = "cyan"))
```

Comment: thanks - `aes` was what I was missing. will accept your answer once the website allows